# Memory Issues in R CRAN Package

Tags: r, loops, package, cran

I have successfully  uploaded R package in CRAN. Now I want to publish its article. Reviewer 2 returned the paper due to **memory usage issues**. Now I am confused about this objection, how to solve this.
Generally, my package is about density plots and I create S3 class for each style of plot. Almost each function used 2 `for` loops otherwise code is not too long. But according to [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html) `for` loops are slow. So what is best alternative?
***Chunk of Code***

```
xxx<-function(y,k,h){
n<-length(y)
 x <- seq(min(y) + 0.05, max(y), length =k)
 K <- matrix(rep(0, k * n), ncol = k)
 fhat <- rep(0, k)
###########Loops###########
for(j in 1:k) {
for(i in 1:n) {
####main code###
}
fhat[j] <- 1/n * (sum(K[, j]))
}
results <- list(x=x, y=fhat)

class ( results ) <-c('list', 'XXX')
results
}
```

`k` is grid point and defined by user. What is the problem and how to solve this? Additionally, they wrote code writing style is not too good; How I can improve this?

Comment: Memory usage issues is not specific enough. Your code example is not sufficient to diagnose this.

Comment: @Roland rest of code consists of S3 class n function. For detail see my edit.

Comment: I don't know the content of the inner loop but `fhat[j] <- 1/n * (sum(K[, j]))` doesn't need a loop. You could use `colSums` instead. However, performance and memory issues are distinct issues. You get into troubles with memory if `k` and `n` get large.

Comment: @Roland sorry, I didn't get your point. What is problematic for performance if I continuously using fhat[j]? Further, can you please give me tips for making my code better....

Comment: Is colSums() is good choice thn fhat[j] specially for R package?